# Where is the rest of the MySQL "HANDLER" documentation?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've been a long time user of `Handlersocket` for MySQL / Percona, but other than MariaDB keeping it going, it's been dead for a long time now.  The final nail in the coffin seemed to be MySQL choosing to go with `Memcached`.

So that in mind, I was looking at all of my alternatives, and in all the noise out there relating to `Handlersocket`, I had missed the existence of MySQL's `HANDLER` capability which, other than the separate socket access, provides very similar features to HS.

The problem is, *handler* is such a ubiquitous term that I'm getting far too much static looking for documentation or examples.  The only page I've been able to locate was the original man page at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/handler.html.  I've run across answers that skirt it like https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4589/23271, but there doesn't seem to be anything more on this feature.

I have questions like:

- There is a `HANDLER .... READ ....` request type, but is there a `HANDLER
  .... WRITE ....` capability?
- Is there a way to restrict the response to a specific selection of
  the table fields? There was in `handlersocket`, but I don't see any
  reference to it on the man page.
- What other capabilities or features does `HANDLER` have?

If you can answer any of the above, I'd be grateful, or if you have links to any further resources, I'm happy to read up on my own. Thanks!

Comment: How are you using HANDLERs?  I have pondered using them several times, but never came up with a good reason to do so.

Comment: @RickJames Not the same thing as `DECLARE ... HANDLER`, this is some of that static I was talking about.  That type of handler is like an auto-triggered statement based on a condition.  The type I'm talking about is roughly equivilant to `handlersocket` and the `memcached` plugin... a pseudo `NoSQL` interface for the InnoDB storage engine.